# regex for vowels at word boundaries

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm trying to match all words that satisfy the condition of having a vowel occur at the beginning and ending of a word.

What I tried (in JS so I could [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcajw/1/) it):

```
var t = 'are ice apple cat dog'
var u =  t.match(/(\b[aeiou]\w+[aeiou]\b)+/); 
alert (u);  // should match 'are,ice,apple'
```

Comment: ... and sometimes _y_ ! ;-)

Comment: And what specifically is wrong with your solution?

Comment: and w - http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/when-is-w-a-vowel.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give it the [`g` global flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) so it will match all. You could drop the outer `(  )+`, too, as it won't gain you anything.

```
var u =  t.match(/\b[aeiou]\w+[aeiou]\b/g); 
                                        ^
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XTAtc/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all the words that satisfy a condition you need to at the 'g' modifier to your regexpression

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp

```
var t = 'are ice apple cat dog'
var u =  t.match(/(\b[aeiou]\w+[aeiou]\b)+/g); 
alert (u);  // it now matches 'are,ice,apple'
```